# XML to String from Database call - MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to recycle an approach [found here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-xml-data-as-html-using-xslt-in-asp-net-mvc/)
to call a stored procedure from SQL Server, receive an XML response, render the response to a string variable, and process it against an XLST template. I can't seem to get the string variable created correctly. Here's what I'm doing in my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Demo2.Models;

namespace Demo2.Controllers
{
public class CfsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Cfs

    
    public ActionResult Report()
    {
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Test; integrated security=SSPI");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC [TEST].[REPORTSERV].[CFSREPORT] @CFSNUMBER = N'010101-10';", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string response = rdr.ToString();
            con.Close();

            ViewBag.CurrentReport = response;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I run the code I'm getting an error in the transform step in the `tranformObj.Transform(reader, args, writer)` step of the helper CS.

I believe the issue is caused by the string response variable not taking the XML response from the SQL Server as a string.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the `[TEST].[REPORTSERV].[CFSREPORT]' stored procedure source code.

Comment: `rdr.ToString()` doesn't do what you think it does. You should also be disposing your connection and reader objects, and using parameters properly with `SqlParameter` objects

Answer (score 0):

Since my stored procedure is going to return only one record (an XML response), I've changed ExecuteReader to ExecuteScalar and converted the response into a string. It's now working but it looks like some of the XML files I'm getting back are exceeding the size of the string variable.

```
 string rdr = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
       
 ViewBag.CurrentReport = rdr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never provided your SP source code... So it is assumed that it returns an XML data type.

You need to change the following two lines:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string response = rdr.ToString();
```

To the following:

```
using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
   string response = xdoc.ToString();
}
```